# AWS Cognito Change user status to disable

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I want to change user status using code.

I tried lots of codes but nothing worked for me. Can any one provide full working example of this. Some time i am getting this error CognitoIdentityCredentials is not authorized to perform: cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser on resource

```
var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();


AWS.config.update({
    region: 'us-west-2',
    credentials: new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: 'us-west-2:6afd2a7c-b3cd-472f-bead-fdbde8a84a26',
    })
});


var params = {
    UserPoolId: 'us-west-2_Klsadmic5', /* required */
    Username: 'alphagate6' /* required */
};
cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDisableUser(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Comment: I didn't need to set the IdentityPoolId in the AWS.config

Answer (score 2):

The params and the invocation seems to be OK. The error means that the role of your lambda function (I assume that this code snippet is from your lambda function) does not have permission to perform **adminDisableUser**.

You need to find the IAM role of your lambda function and attach a policy that allows this action. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAdminDisableUser",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You may also want to specify certain resources to not allow this action for every user pool.

Comment: this is similar to how I got it to work setting this in the serverless.yml (serverless framework)

Answer (score 1):

I had this feature to enable/disable users in one application and here is How I have implemented the feature

1. Gave lambda necessary permissions to perform enable/disable

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cognito-idp:AdminEnableUser",
                "cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:cognito-idp:<region>:<account-id>:userpool/<user-pool-id>",
                "arn:aws:cognito-idp:<region>:<account-id>:userpool/<user-pool-id>"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

2. Initializing AWS SDK

```js
AWS.config.update({
  region: "us-east-1",
});
const cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  apiVersion: "2016-04-18",
});
const UserPoolId = "<pool-id>";
```

3. Created one method to handle enable/disable

```js
const accountActions = (action, username) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const params = {
      UserPoolId /* required */,
      Username: username /* required */,
    };
    if (action == "disable") {
      cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminDisableUser(params, function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
          rej(err);
        } else {
          res(data);
        }
      });
    } else {
      cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminEnableUser(params,function(err,data) {
        if (err) {
          rej(err);
        } else {
          res(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone trying to do this via Amplify.

edit the `"AmplifyResourcesPolicy"` (for my project, it's in the `cloudformation-template.json`)

```
"AmplifyResourcesPolicy": {
    "DependsOn": ["LambadExecutionRole"],
    "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
    ...
    "PolicyDocument": {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "cognito-idp:AdminDisableUser",
                    "cognito-idp:AdminEnableUser",
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "Fn:Join": [
                        "arn:aws:cognito-idp:",
                        {
                            "Ref": "AWS::Region"
                        },
                        ":",
                        {
                            "Ref": "AWS::AccountId"
                        },
                        ":userpool/",
                        {
                            "Ref": "<user-pool-id>"
                        }
                    ]
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

If Your aim is to enable/disable cognito user as an admin disregard this. 
Just be aware that the admin enable/disable enables/disabled the user as an administrator.
Not disableing the user account (login etc) which is where you might be getting the error from.

Comment: That doesn't hold true. I am able to disable any user inside a user pool using another user who has according permissions (set in a lambda role policy). After disabling the user, he cannot login and perform any actions.